# Can't get my app reviewed in Facebook API

Tags: api, facebook, messenger

I can't get my app to be reviewed through the Facebook API.

The app is purely a facebook messenger bot, and the app type is "business".

I have configured the specific permissions I need, however I recieve an error that states "You do not have any platforms eligible for review. Please configure a platform on your Settings page."

I also cannot add my app domain in the basic settings, as whenever I press save changes, the url does not save and disappears.

Additionally there is no option to make my app live.

Any advice?

[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yw8w4.png)

Comment: _"Additionally there is no option to make my app live."_ - there is no "live" or "development" mode for business apps. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/build-and-test/app-modes: _"Note that Business apps do not have app modes and instead rely exclusively on access levels."_

Answer (score 0):

I am leaving this answer in the event someone else needs it. It was an answer suggested by Facebook support when I encountered the same problem.

Go into App Settings and add a platform "Website"

Just add your website URL.

If the requested permission is just Messenger based then the website will not be accessed or tested.